# imeoptions on HTC devices

Tags: android

I cannot see the imeoptions like done and like on HTC devices while same code works fine with Motorola.

Here is the code

```
<TableRow>
            <EditText android:hint="Name" 
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:background="@drawable/chegg_topcorner_rounded" 
            android:layout_width = "50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity ="left"
            android:paddingLeft = "10dp"
            android:paddingTop = "9dp"
            android:paddingBottom = "9dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
```

Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

If by "imeoptions like done" you mean the action button, HTC Sense does not appear to support the action button, except for its own purposes. Soft keyboards are not required to support the action button, so you cannot assume it exists on any given device, or even any given user (if they downloaded and are using a third-party soft keyboard).

BTW, for source code, when you paste it into a question, highlight it and choose the toolbar button above the editor that looks like a set of binary digits -- that will ensure the code gets formatted as source. In particular, if you paste in XML and do not do this, it does not show up.