# How can I use the android landscape keyboard buttons?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, landscape

I have an activity with two EditTexts. If, in landscape mode, I select the first EditText, the keyboard that is displayed has a "next" button which should allow me to type in the second EditText. Likewise, the second EditText has a "done" button, which I would like to handle for completing the activity. How can I handle the selection of these buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is fairly little documentation on how to solve this issue. I found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276448/android-edit-text-go-button). Basically, you can add an IMEoption for each of the EditTexts:
For the first one:

```
      android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

For the second one:

```
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

To handle these in the code, try something like this:

```
EditText departureAddress, destinationAddress;
departureAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.departure);
//Set the action of the "next" button to bring destinationAddress to focus
destinationAddress(new OnEditorActionListener(){
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
  if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
      destinationAddress.requestFocus();
  }
  return true;
}
  });
  destinationAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.destination);
  //Set the action of the "done" button to handle the map query
  destinationAddress.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
  if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
      //Handle map query
  }
  return true;
}
  });
```