# Can I change default android keyboard Text

Tags: android, android-keypad

How to change label of any key on Android default keyboard.

I want to do something like this,

[image]

Comment: Not possible, unless you are going to create your own keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive this by using Use [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html):

```
KeyboardView kbd = new KeyboardView(context);
kbd.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.customlayout));

kbd.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new OnKeyboardActionListener() {
    ....
}
```

now you have kd which is a normal view.

The nice thing about this is that R.xml.custom refers to /res/xml/custom.xml, which defines in xml the layout of the keyboard. For more information on this file, look here: [Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html), [Keyboard.Row](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Row.html), [Keyboard.Key](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html).

Comment: :I just want to change a key label

Comment: you couldn't change only single key from built-in-keyboard,you have to customise the keyboard to want your required output

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own keyboard to change the text and style of keyboard.
[Custom Keyboard](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

> you should have a look at ImeActionLabel or ImeActionId

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/some_edittext"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:imeOptions="actionSend">
</EditText>
```

[Read this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276448/android-edit-text-go-button)