# android: how to get the "ok" button when inputing text

Tags: android, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an application where user needs to input some text. When I click the editText area a keyboard appears and then I input the text after which I have to press the "back" key on my phone to hide the keyboard and then press the submit button which is getting annoying.

How do I get that "ok" button that does it for me which I am used to? I have Android version 2.3.6 on my phone. Is this even available at this API level ?

Comment: Go to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276448/android-edit-text-go-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276448/android-edit-text-go-button)

Comment: Go to ur XML file to the EditText and add imeOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onEditorActionListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html on your `EditText`.

Also see: `EditorInfo` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html